# Counter not updating for a empty table

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have this cassandra table:

```
CREATE TABLE object_counters
(
    object_level_1 bigint,
    object_level_2 bigint,
    object_level_3 bigint,
    upvote counter,
    comment counter,
    downvote counter,
    rate_0_0 counter,
    rate_0_5 counter,
    rate_1_0 counter,
    rate_1_5 counter,
    rate_2_0 counter,
    rate_2_5 counter,
    rate_3_0 counter,
    rate_3_5 counter,
    rate_4_0 counter,
    rate_4_5 counter,
    rate_5_0 counter,
    PRIMARY KEY((object_level_1, object_level_2), object_level_3)
);
```

and this query:

```
UPDATE ks_mobApp.object_counters SET comment=comment+1 WHERE object_level_1=163844152 AND object_level_2=163844152 AND object_level_3=163844152;
```

when table is blank and running this query is not updating the counter

Comment: this is perfectly valid statement and should execute and update. What is the error you are seeing.

Comment: Are you trying to reuse the counters? if you do, ensure you drop the table or truncate. Deletes make the counters appear as zero, but under the hood they make the deleted keys unusable,so any subsequent update is not performed.And this is by design.

Comment: what do you mean by `Are you trying to reuse the counters? `

Comment: @AravindChamakura i am not getting any error

Comment: @manish It's working fine for me on Cassandra 3.7. comment is incremented from 0 to 1 first time. If I execute again, it has become 2. What is your output of select query? Is it null or zero? Or there is no row inserted?

Comment: @manish I think what xmas79 mean is: you have created the partition with that primary key and dropped the row. Now you are trying to create the row with same primary key again?

Comment: No record is inserted at all. You mean once i deleted a `object_level_1, object_level_2, object_level_3` pair i should not insert the same record again ?

Comment: Removal of counters is provided for definitive removal only. http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Counters